# Enabling sound over HDMI / DP

Tags: nvidia, sound, alsa, hdmi, displayport

My sound over displayport was not working and looks like it is a known problem with Nvidia graphics cards.

[Here the alsa report](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=dd27505662340bcdb98abd6b53d092de56b15ec6) where I can see that only the HDA Intel module is loaded.

To fix it, this worked to me: https://github.com/hhfeuer/nvhda

```
git clone git@github.com:hhfeuer/nvhda.git
cd nvhda
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe nvhda
sudo tee /proc/acpi/nvhda <<<ON
```

After executing it, I went to `Settings -> Sound -> Output Device` and select the new HDMI / DisplayPort option.

[Here the alsa report after load the module](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=38186c18fd365f35c9d6692d19a3da3f94d67645) where I can read a new NVidia soundcard.

It is working, so I load the kernel module automatically

```
sudo echo 'nvhda' >> /etc/modules
```

**Problem and questions:**

- Every time that I restart the laptop, I need to execute `sudo tee /proc/acpi/nvhda <<<ON` again to enable the sound.
  How to do it automatically after loading the nvhda module?
- Is really strange that Ubuntu does not fix this problem. Am I missing something? There is another way?

System Info:

- MSI GS30 2M Shadow
- VGA

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Crystal Well 
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 08)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 
1060 6GB] (rev a1)
```

- OS

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 19.04
Release:  19.04
Codename: disco
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time that I restart the laptop, I need to execute sudo tee /proc/acpi/nvhda <<

/proc is a VIRTUAL filesystem that gets recreated on every boot. Generally I would expect there to be a configuration file where you can set this. If you need to do it like this add a line to

```
/etc/rc.local
```

before the `exit 0` and it will get executed on every boot. Not ideal but if it works you only need to wait for a fix to arrive.

> Is really strange that Ubuntu does not fix this problem. Am I missing something? There is another way?

That really depends on the cause of the problem and how difficult it is. This is a kernel related problem so the Ubuntu team is probably waiting for a fix to arrive. There is a discussion on [bug.freedesktop.org](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75985#c37) and it reads as being pretty difficult. [This topic on nvidia](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6908) puts a relation to nvidia-drm and systemd. If it is a bug in the DRM part that would make it out of reach of the kernel maintainers and it would be nVidia that probably needs to fix it.

All in all. I trust the Ubuntu team enough to fix what they can and expect this problem to be out of their reach.